# Solving a recurrence relation with two variables

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recurrence-relation, binary-trees

I have this function which traverses each node of a left child-right sibling binary tree once and I want to solve the recurrence relation of the function.

First of all I think the relation looks like this:
`T(n) = 1+m[4+T(n-m)] = 1+4m+mT(n-m)`

Where `m` is the number of nodes on a level and `n` the total amount of nodes in the tree.

Is this correct? And how could I solve this recurrence relation with two variables?

```
void maxWidth(Node node, int height, vector<int> &width){
    if(node==nullptr){
        return;
    }
    while(node!=nullptr){
        if(width.size()==height){
            width.push_back(0);
        }
        if(width.size()>height){
            width[height]=width[height]+1;
        }
        if(node->left_child!=nullptr){
            maxWidth(node->left_child,height+1,width);
        }
        node=node->right_sib;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on solving a recurrence formula, you might want to compute $T$ based on the *height* of the tree first. Computing $T$ based on the number of nodes is much more complicated, and the $T(n-m)$ there is not correct - it needs to be $T(n-\sum_{i=1}^m{k_i})$ where $k_i$ is the size of the sub-tree which is rooted in the $i$'th child.

Otherwise (which is what I recommend doing), just notice that you will visit each node at most once. In each visit you will pay no more than $O(1)$ before each recursive call, and hence this algorithm will total to be $O(n)$.

However the above reasoning will need to be formalized if you want to keep it as a proof. That is, you will have to prove that indeed you will not visit each node more than once.

Comment: I knew it was O(n) but I didn't know how to prove it, thanks for pointing out that T(n-m) was wrong in the formula

Comment: If you would have kept it, the result would have been enormous, something like $\Omega(m^{\frac{n}{m}})$

Comment: how would you compute T using the height of the tree?

Comment: Assuming the tree is balanced, $T(h)=O(m)+mT(h-1)$. If I'm not mistaken, solving this yields $T(h)=O(\sum_{i=1}^h m^i)=O(\sum_{i=1}^\log_m(n) m^i)=O(m^{\log_m(n)})=O(n)$